# Marshalling a Pointer to Array of Struct in C#

Tags: callback, marshalling

In C++, we have a callBack function which is defined as
     int GetFunctionTable( FunctionTag **ppFunctionTable )

During initialization, this function gets called and we are to return an array of FunctionTag into it. Size of array is to be returned by the return value. In C++, the body would be like

```
   {
       static FunctionTag * ourFunctionTable = {{....}, { ...}, ... };
       *ppFunctionTable = ourFunctionTable;
   }
```

Most examples that I see on net, I have seen talk about calling a function. This is a call back function, so memory allocation is ours but the variable that will accept the return value is fixed.

out IntPtr OR ref IntPtr do not work.

Comment: This is vague, at least some idea how native code is going to call the C# code would be important.  The argument is an array of delegate objects in .NET, passed as *ref*.  With the delegate type declared to be an exact match with *FunctionTag*.  You also need to store this array so it can't be garbage collected.  A static variable is good.

Comment: Hans,... Thank you for commenting... This function is part of AmiBroker C++ SDK and is defined with Macro PLUGINAPI which expands to "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)". When user starts AmiBroker, it calls all .DLLs in plugin folder one by one and this function is the one that allows plugin to define custom functions... Even in C++, most users define it static because info in this table does not change in runtime....

Comment: @ https://github.com/kriasoft/amibroker, there is .NET SDK which contains a file named updateexports.exe. This executable is command line app and it simply disassembles a .NET DLL, renames all public static functions of a class named Plugin and then recompiles DLL, so exports become visible to C++.